# numpy float vs decimal.Decimal()

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, django-rest-framework

My question is about the usage of standard float python type vs decimal.Decimal(). I'm trying to expose a local python package via API. The serialization process from Django rest framework returns me `Decimal` types as the built in field DecimalField is able to perform basic validation.

If I apply then my internal function to numpy array of Decimals it fails. However, if I first convert them to floats everything works like a charm. Hence the question: Is it not save to use Decimal types for functions using certain numpy capabilities? What is the standard to do the validation in django if you ultimately want to call certain numpy features? If Decimal is not a choice for numpy then you basically can forget the DecimalField for validation within Django

Comment: Can you add example of usage. From this I guess you'll be fine with `my_arr = np.array(myDecimals, dtype='float')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decimal are a lot more exact than floats. If you want to see the difference, open a Python shell and try:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(0.3)
Decimal('0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875')
>>> Decimal('0.3')
Decimal('0.3')
>>>
```

The first one is a decimal created from a float, the other is created from a string. As you can see, float are using an approximation which usually is fine but sometime isn't.

So either you should drop Decimal and use float - probably the best option in your case since you want to use numpy - or cast the decimal into float and back with the approximation shown above.